# Laravel routes are not working after updated from 5.3 to 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

After upgraded to Laravel 5.4.2 from Laravel 5.3
Routes are not working.

But routes are exist

```
php artisan route:list
```

Shows all the routes

Got this in log file

```
[2017-08-28 12:35:28] local.DEBUG: 404: http://laravel.local/test
{
    "type": "404",
    "url": "http:\/\/laravel.local\/test",
    "method": "GET",
    "data": []
}
```

Am using vagrant, homestead for my local environment. 
my routes/web.php file looks,

```
Route::group([
    'prefix'     => 'en',
    'middleware' => [
        'auth'
    ],
], function() {
    Route::get('/test', 'HomeController@test');
    Route::get('/post', 'PostController@start');
    Route::post('/post', 'PostController@post');
});
```

Comment: Run `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: cleared everything but still same issue. @Troyer

Comment: Restart apache2 on vagrant check if is displaying any error.

Comment: Am using nginx and restarted that also. not working.

Comment: Create a simple route: `Route::get('foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});` if this is not working is 100% sure something wrong happen in your web service.

Answer (score 0):

Am using another route group function in web.php and it uses a custom middleware for localisation that causes the issue. Thanks.